# losing type information when recognizing tokens in LEX

Tags: regex, bison, yacc, lex

I am trying to parse a config file using lex and yacc/bison.The sample file is shown below.

```
[section1]
attr1=1234567
attr2=848329832499934
[section2]
attr3=1233422
attr2=849999934834798
```

To recognize the values for the attributes listed above,I use the following regular expressions.

```
DIGIT [0-9]
NUM   {DIGIT}+
```

Now in my specific example `attr1` has a type of `uint32_t` and `attr2` has a type of `uint64_t`

However I cannot recognize this.In otherwords I need to have a symbol table (which I statically define) from where I can lookup the type so that I can populate the appropriate type.

Is there any other approach to solve this problem? How do dynamically typed languages like python solve this issue.?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to type the constant (or other token) based on the token itself.  So if a sequence of digits token has value in the range 0..2<sup>32</sup>-1, then it would be a `unit32_t`, otherwise it would be some other type (and corresponding token) capable of holding the value.

In the case of python, there's `int` type capable of holding integers that fit in a single word (what that is depends on the machine you're running on), and then there's `long` type capable of handling any larger integer.